# Rails - How to include the mail_to helper inside of a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

in my controller I need to format a json object, which is why I need to include several helpers.

So far I have the following in my controller:

```
  include ApplicationHelper
  include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper
  include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper
```

This works great for simple_format, problem is when the comment.content has a email address, rails trys to do a mailto link which breaks, showing the following error in the logs: "NoMethodError (undefined method `mail_to' for...."

Any ideas on how to add it in? I tried adding   include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper but that did not work.

Thanks

Comment: I get this error when I include the UrlHelper: "undefined local variable or method `controller"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use **view_context** in your controller when doing 'view' tasks like generating links. The good thing about it is you don't have to **include** the view helpers in your controller.

e.g. in your controller you can create a variable which will be a html link with link_to.

```
link = view_context.link_to("link", your_awesome_path(@awesome))
```

I have not tested this but you should hopefully be able to do this in your controller:

```
email_link = view_context.mail_to(@user.email)
```

RyanB uses **view_context** in the paper_trail railscast: [255-undo-with-paper-trail](http://railscasts.com/episodes/255-undo-with-paper-trail)

Not sure if this will solve your problem, because not sure what your doing with the JSON helpers etc. but it may help.

Answer (score 0):

I had solved this by the following

```
class CrazyPresenter
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper
  include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper
  include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper

  def controller
    nil
  end

end
```